# How to parse the information from a definition list

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a simple definition list that I am trying to parse the information out of and put into variables I can use later in my code. I would like to get the Product Version, Serial number, System Time and Uptime from this table.

```
<table class="tabbed_table" cellspacing="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <dl class="table-display">
          <dt class="wide">Product version: </dt>
          <dd class="wide">1.0</dd>
          <dt class="wide">Serial number:</dt>
          <dd class="wide">D00005</dd>
          <dt class="wide">System Time:</dt>
          <dd class="wide">Tuesday, October 07, 2014 04:04PM CDT</dd>
          <dt class="wide">Uptime:</dt>
          <dd class="wide"> 16:04:17 up 1 day, 3:32, 1 user, load average: 0.00, 0.04, 0.00 </dd>   
        </dl>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see how you did it without code. Like to share what you're doing?

Comment: Will the order of the data change?

Comment: The version, serial number, time and uptime will all be different values. But the "Product"."Serial number" etc will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DList class (in Watir-WebDriver) and Dl class (in Watir-Classic) have a `to_hash` method that creates a hash out of the dl element. The keys will be the dt element text and the values will be the dd element text.

```
# Convert the dl element into a hash:
descriptions = browser.dl(class: 'table-display').to_hash

# Output the values (or any other usage):
p descriptions['Product version:']
#=> "1.0"
p descriptions['Serial number:']
#=> "D00005"
p descriptions['System Time:']
#=> "Tuesday, October 07, 2014 04:04PM CDT"
p descriptions['Uptime:']
#=> "16:04:17 up 1 day, 3:32, 1 user, load average: 0.00, 0.04, 0.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

The most precise selector you can use here is xPath:

```
a = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
a.goto 'http://THEPAGEURLGOESHERE.COM'
descriptions = a.dts(xpath: "//table[@class='tabbed_table']//dl[@class='table-display']/dt[@class='wide']").map { |element| element.text }
values = a.dds(xpath: "//table[@class='tabbed_table']//dl[@class='table-display']/dd[@class='wide']").map { |element| element.text }
p descriptions.zip(values) #=>
# [["Product version:", "1.0"], ["Serial number:", "D00005"], ["System Time:", "Tuesday, October 07, 2014 04:04PM CDT"], ["Uptime:", "16:04:17 up 1 day, 3:32, 1 user, load average: 0.00, 0.04, 0.00"]]
a.close
```